# double integral evaluation

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral $\int\int_R(x^2-2y^2) \, dA$ where $R$ is the first quadrant region between the circles of radius $4$ and radius $5$.

I am having troubles with finding the limits of the integral. Thank you!

Comment: You could use the fact that for a circle of radius $r$, the equation is (centered at the origin) $x^2+y^2=r^2$, and then change to polar coordinates.

Comment: *Hint*: $\int\int_R(x^2-2y^2)dA= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_4^5(r^2(1+rsin\theta))rdrd\theta$ and you can do $r^4sin\theta$ by parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use polar coordinates.

$x^2=r^2\cos^2{\theta};y^2=r^2\sin^2{\theta}$

$x^2-2y^2=r^2(\cos^2{\theta}-2\sin^2{\theta})$

$x^2-2y^2=r^2(1-\sin^2{\theta}-2\sin^2{\theta})=r^2(1-3\sin^2{\theta})$

$x^2-2y^2=r^2(1-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}cos2{\theta})=r^2(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}cos2{\theta}))$

$\iint_Rx^2-2y^2\,dx\,dy=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{4}^5r^3\,dr\,d\theta +\frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{4}^5r^3\cos2{\theta}\,dr\,d\theta$

Note that "first cuadrant" means $\theta$  goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: thank you! that really help me

Comment: You're welcome.